# PSD document size for mdpi Android design

Tags: android, photoshop

I have an iPhone app design PSD, that I need adapt to an Android app design.

I have read five different official documentation articles, several blog posts, Stack Overflow answers, template PSD files, you name it.

I now know that my mission is to make a design in the mdpi baseline density, and then use the 3:4:6:8 ratio rule to extract bitmap drawables for each density.

However, the one thing that every one of the smart people who wrote everything I read seemed to neglect to tell me is what exact pixel values should I use to create said mdpi design.

Every example I've read starts with "For example, if you have a 100x100 icon in mdpi...". Well I have no idea how many pixels my icons are in mdpi.

[This documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) says that "normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp". I thought the word "normal" applied to screen *sizes*, not *densities*. And what's "at least"? What if I make drawables in the 'at least' size and then somebody has a screen bigger than that? There's also a table at the end from which I can gather that mdpi screens are either 320x480 or 1280x800. So that's all cleared up then.

I'm not an Android dev, nor do I aspire to be one. I'm just one sad, exasperated designer who'd like to know the exact numbers I should put in Photoshop's "Image Size" dialog to turn my Retina iPhone design (640x960 good ol' fashioned pixels) into a size representative of mdpi in Android. Please someone provide me with these numbers. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 640x960 iPhone res with 326dpi, you're trying to get to the 160dpi (mdpi) level.

So, this means you need to multiply your dimensions by 160/326 or 0.49. This will yield a template of 314x471.

Also checkout http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/ which will have some device screen templates that you can import into Photoshop or another editor. From there, if you use, say, a template with a phone that is HDPI, you can scale accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First some links that may clarify the stretchable concepts of android design:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension
http://blog.edwinevans.me/?p=131

" I thought the word "normal" applied to screen sizes, not densities."

I have a phone with a 4" screen and 480x800 resolution. That is about 240dpi
Another phone has a 4" screen 320x480 res, but only 160dpi (mdpi).

Think of it as trying to print a 16 mega pixel photo on an old fashioned 150dpi printer in full resolution. You'd end up with a HUGE printout.

To avoid that resolution problem, the sp/dp are used in android, making screens of very different resolution look very similar.

You should be able to set photoshop to present your designs to you in the desired target DPI.

I hoped this helps a bit to de-confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

For an mdpi baseline photoshop canvas, the dimensions are:

width:360px
height:640px
ppi: 72

This will give you and 16:9 format screen, yo can easily scale components to 1920x1080 xxhdpi screens.